# SQL: Order results by (optional) relationship

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, relation

I have two tables `Post (id, ..., creationdate)` and `Post_Has_Post(parent_id, child_id)`.

Some Posts can be part of a parent<->child relation and have a corresponding entry in the `Post_Has_Post`-Table.

What I'm trying to do is getting a list of posts ordered by their creationdate. Any children of other posts however should be inserted after their parent in the result.
Now of course it's easy to order by creationdate, but i'm out of ideas for the second sorting condition. Is there a way to do that at all?

```
Post                              Post_Has_Post
+------+-------+--------------+   +-----------+----------+
| id   | ...   | creationdate |   | parent_id | child_id |
+------+-------+--------------+   +-----------+----------+
| 1    | ...   | 2010-11-01   |   |  1        |  3       |
| 2    | ...   | 2010-11-02   |   +-----------+----------+
| 3    | ...   | 2010-11-03   |
+------+-------+--------------+
```

I need a result sorted like this:

```
Post
+------+-------+--------------+   
| id   | ...   | creationdate |  
+------+-------+--------------+  
| 1    | ...   | 2010-11-01   |  
| 3    | ...   | 2010-11-03   | 
| 2    | ...   | 2010-11-02   |
+------+-------+--------------+
```

Is there a way to solve this through sorting?

Comment: Do you allow multi-level parent-child relationships? I.e.: 1 is 3's parent and 3 is 2's parent. That would change things as well...

Comment: Also, you design allow a post have two parents. How would your output be, then?

Comment: @Adrian you're right, i'll get rid of the relationship table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the parent always comes before the child, this should work.

```
SELECT p.id, ..., creationdate
    FROM Post p
        LEFT JOIN Post_Has_Post php
            ON p.id = php.child_id
    ORDER BY COALESCE(php.parent_id, p.id),
             creationdate
```

Comment: I was expecting a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` for this, but if it works for OP I'll up it :)

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of that function until now!

Answer (score 2):

You should not have the table Post_Has_Parent.  Instead look into
adding a column to the Post table of "parent_id" and using a
relationship between post_id and parent_id and a self join.  When
someone posts a reply to a post, just put the parents post id as the
parent_id of the new post.  This will allow you to store the
relationship in one table.

Depending on the DBMS you can look into using:

Oracle: Connect_be

```
select seq_num, post_text, parent_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(seq_num,
'/') AS PATH, level
 from post
start with seq_num = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR seq_num = parent_id;
```

SQL Server: Common Table Expressions

```
;with posts as
(

      select seq_num, post_text, parent_id, 0 AS generation,
              CAST(seq_num as varchar(50)) as path
              from recurs_test
              where parent_id is NULL
      UNION ALL
      select e.seq_num, e.post_text, e.parent_id, generation + 1,
              CAST(rtrim(p.path) + '/' +  CAST(e.seq_num as varchar(5)) as
varchar(50)) as path
              from recurs_test e
              inner join posts p
              on e.parent_id = p.seq_num

)

select seq_num, name, parent_id, dir, generation from
managers order by dir;
```

MYSQL:  You are going to have to look into using some sort of tree
traversal algorithm and do a depth first search.  They are all pretty
complex and usually involve storing something ( the path, a left and
right value, etc ) in the database.  The reason is that MYSQL does not
allow any recursive select statements ( correct me if I am wrong so I
can redo some code that I have written!! )

Comment: As true as this may be , it does not answer the question. It should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: This doesn't address the question of ordering, though.  Maybe post a suggestion on how you would display in the desired order with your proposed structure.

Comment: @adrian - his/her rep is too low to comment I think.

Comment: @JNK I guess so. I liked your constructive comment to @jworrin, I think we need more of this in SO. I save my downvotes to very wrong unsavable answers.

Comment: @JNK - You are correct, I did not have the rep to comment until after I posted.  Once I posted, it gave me more rep and I now have the ability to comment.

Comment: @jworrin - Upvoted for the edit.  Also, I formatted your code for you.  Take a look at the changes, and make sure to use the included code tags when you post code samples so it's easy to read.

Comment: @JNK - Thank you for formatting the code for me and not jumping down my throat for not doing it!!  I will keep code formatting in mind from now on when I post!

Answer (score 1):

You won't have the dates in a single column, but IMHO that's a little confusing anyway. You could choose to show the child thread date or parent thread date in whatever UI is presenting the data:

```
SELECT Parent.ID, Parent.CreationDate ParentCreationDate,
       Child.CreationDate ChildCreationDate
FROM Post Parent LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Post_Has_Post PHP ON Parent.ID = PHP.Parent_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Post Child ON PHP.Child_ID = Child.ID
ORDER BY Parent.CreationDate, Child.CreationDate;
```

Comment: You could use `COALESCE(Parent.CreationDate, Child.Creationdate) AS CreationDate` to display it in a single field.

Comment: @JNK: Good point. In fact my query should probably be doing that for the parent/child post ID as well.